# C#.net exception when trying to reference db connection via Test unit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, web-config, database-connection

My DB Connection dosnt work, can someone please tell me why?

I run this from a unit test in VS 2010. Simple Assert.IsTrue(testDbConnection) and it fails.
i'v also tried running it in normal mode as a web application and I get the same exception.

please note the XXXXX are ofcourse done with purpose.

web.config

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="DomainDatabase" connectionString="Data Source=XXXXXXXXXX;Initial Catalog=domain;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=campain_xxx;Password=XXXXXXXXX" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

My test method

```
 public bool testDBConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DomainDatabase"].ConnectionString);
                sqlCon.Open();
                sqlCon.Close();

                return true;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                return false;
            }

        }
```

This gives me the exception

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: Don't know if it matters but `connectionString` is spelled with a lower-case 'c' in your configuration and an upper-case 'c' in the test code.

Comment: Where do you exactly get the exception ?

Comment: I run this from a unit test in VS 2010. Simple Assert.IsTrue(testDbConnection)

Comment: You said web.config? VS 2010 test suite unit test would be using an app.config........

Comment: Now I also tried it by simply running my web application, still fails. Same error

Comment: fyi, If the focus of your unit tests is not the db layer, you must look at mocking your dblayer. http://code.google.com/p/moq/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As neither the tests or the web application is working, it's likely that the problem you are seeing is because the configuration is not being loaded. I suspect that the following...

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DomainDatabase"]
```

...returns null. The *NullReferenceException* is thrown when you attempt to access the *ConnectionString* property on that null object (reference).  I would verify that your configuration for connectionStrings matches the definition defined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings.aspx):

You can verify that your settings aren't being loaded with the following test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void VerifyThatMyDatabaseConnectionStringExists()
{
    Assert.IsNotNull(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DomainDatabase"]);
}
```

If this test fails, add an app.config to your test project with the proper configuration. You will know that you have solved this problem when ...[you can take this pebble from my hand](http://www.google.ca/search?q=when%20you%20can%20take%20this%20pebble%20from%20my%20hand) -- no wait, wrong reference -- this test passes.

Tip: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344069/can-a-unit-test-project-load-the-target-applications-app-config-file/344233#344233) suggests you should write tests to verify that your settings are present to prevent madness.

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy app.config file wich has connectionString into Test-project and it works!