# C# Primitive Types or Complex Types as Method Signatures?

Tags: c#, primitive-types, complextype

What are the pros and cons of using Primitve Types or Complex Types?

When should you use primitive types over complex types and vice versa?

i.e.:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int IQ { get; set; }
}


public void FooPrimitiveTypes (string firstName, string lastName, int age, int IQ)
{

}

public void FooComplexTypes(Person person)
{

}
```

Comment: I swear this was asked just yesterday.

Comment: link? my question is edited ... well ...

Comment: Use what type suits the problem best.  Why are you hung up on primitives verus (what you call) complex types?  What are you trying to accomplish?  This question is too vague as it stands, it needs context.

Comment: This question is basically asking what is the benefit of OOP.

Comment: have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288859/ways-of-keeping-configuration-code-out-of-logic-code-using-dependency-injection have a look at the conversation from Bryan Watts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. To pass each property separately are generally used when you are dealing with disjoint values. Also, sometimes used on constructors. Bad practice.
2. This way is preferred when the values are related.

Why #1 is a bad practice - suppose you needed to add `height`. I'd much rather update one class by adding another property, instead of 50 methods.

Comment: +1 - This is pretty much what I would write. The only reason not to use the complex object is in the edge case where you want deep copies.

Comment: @Daniel A. White: What about a configuration class with 20 properties? Should I really have them separately?

Comment: @Rookian: That depends on whether you'll have a method that wants to use all of them.

Comment: No. Its all related because its configuration.

Comment: @Rookian I'll add that there is a third way: `Dictionary`/`Hashtable`. I don't like very much this way, but still it's present and used.

Comment: @Daniel A. White. So it does not really matter if all of the properties are used. It just has to be the same category/scope/concern?

Answer (score 0):

Does Foo conceptually deal with a Person? Does all (or at least most) of Person get used by Foo, or is it just using a few bits of information that happen to be in Person? Is Foo likely to ever deal with something that's not a Person? If Foo is InsertPersonIntoDB(), then it's probably best to deal with Person.

If Foo is PrintName(), then maybe PrintName(string FirstName, string LastName) is more appropriate (or alternatively, you might define a Name class instead and say that a person has a Name).

If you find yourself creating half initialized temporary Person objects just to pass to Foo, then you probably want to break down the parameters.

Comment: the Person is just a really simple example. Well no not all properties of the class Person will be used in the method. Have a look at my posted link and the given conversation. It is more about passing a configuration object into methods.

Answer (score 0):

Something to note is that when you use primitives they are being passed by value... the object reference is also being passed by value but since all the underlying references to the values are references it is effectively pass by reference.  So depending on what you are doing this pass by value or pass by reference could be of importance.  Also in the first case modifications to the primitives will not affect the values of the variables in the calling scope however modifying the object passed in will affect the object in the calling scope.