# Unit test SerializableConfigurationSection programmatically

Tags: c#, unit-testing, configuration

I'm using strongly typed configuration sections in my project and want to unit test a particular area which throws an exception when a setting isn't set-up correctly.

**A snippet of the configuration class:**

```
public class EmailSettings : SerializableConfigurationSection, IEmailSettings
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("from", IsRequired = true)]
    public string From
    {
      get
      {
        ...
      }
      set
      {
        ...
      }
    }
    ...
}
```

**Sample test method:**

```
[TestMethod]
public void something_describing_this_test()
{
  EmailSettings settings = new EmailSettings();
  settings.From;
}
```

I expect that `SerializableConfigurationSection` and its inners are looking for a web.config (or similar) to read xml config from.

How can I get in the middle and 'mock' the configuration to enable me to pipe custom values to test for certain conditions?  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344069/can-a-unit-test-project-load-the-target-applications-app-config-file) (using `ConfigurationManager` methods) appears to do it via a physical config file in the assembly - is this the only way or can I get in there programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could generate one in your test fixture setup, and then load it like described in the answer to this question:

[Loading custom configuration files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505566/loading-custom-configuration-files)

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any way to do this programmatically so this looks like the only way forward - thanks for answering.