# AppConfig in a VS 2008 test project?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, configuration-files, app-config

I've just added my first test project to a VS 2008 solution.  I have a component I'd like to use in a unit test; the component calls System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.GetConfig() to get a setting, and I'd like for that call to work in my test.  Any ideas how I can do this?  I don't see any app.config in the project, so I'm not sure if that's an option in this instance.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys.  Great info, but what I wound up putting an App.Config in the test project and adding the appropriate  sections in it.  Works good now.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here : [Unit testing the app.config file with NUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168931/unit-testing-the-app-config-file-with-nunit)

I believe you can set up a config file to work with the test runner.  Find its executable and use a post-build action to copy the application file to "[TestRunner.exe].config".

Answer (score 1):

You can mock that call. Using TypeMock, you would go like this:

```
var mockConfigurationManager = MockManager.Mock(typeof(ConfigurationManager));
var appSettings = new NameValueCollection { { "key", "value" } };
mockConfigurationManager.ExpectGetAlways("AppSettings", appSettings);
```